# Adobe Illustrator SVG files looking unclean

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I am using Adobe Illustrator from Creative Cloud, most up-to-date version.

I have purchased an asset from Adobe Stock and I wanted to save it from .ai to .svg and use it on a web page.

This is how the asset looks on my monitor when I edit it in Adobe Illustator:

[image]

Then, when I use the EXPORT or SAVE AS and choose .svg, I open the .svg file in Chrome and Firefox and it looks like this:
[image]

The shadows are all messed up, it looks like someone turned water over the design and it turned into an oily design. I am not expert in Adobe Illustrator. I just use it to do minor changes to files, so I have no idea what is the problem, maybe I am missing some plugin or something. I tried all possible ways of saving the image as SVG and it always looks like that.

Here is how my export settings look like:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You may want to add a bit more decimal places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Illustrator add anchor points to all elements a couple of times.

In the menu bar go to Object -> Path -> Add Anchors

Then, in the SVG options panel, increase the Decimal Places to the max *(7 I think?)* and see if the results are any better.

Comment: Thx, that did the trick!